# Combine Two Lists of Dictionaries

Tags: c#-4.0

I have two Lists of dictionaries.
Both are not not null.
How to merge these lists?
which of the following is better way?

1. dicA.Concat(dicB).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value)
2. Dictionary Mydictionary = new Dictionary();
   Mydictonary.Union(secondDictionary).ToDictionary( pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);

Comment: Do you have List<Dictionary<>> or just a Dictionary<>? Some code examples could help..

Comment: Merge to what? To one `List<Dictionary>`? To one `Dictionary`?

Comment: Two different lists of dictionaries I have to combine them together

Comment: I have List<Dictionary<string,string>>

Comment: I Think Concat will work fine????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
var finalList = list1.Union(list2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use SelectMany operator of linq, il your merge treatment is complicated